# Are there any tests of quantum field theory one can do using everyday objects?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, home-experiment

One of the reasons I love physics is because many of the theories I can test using everyday objects around me.  For example I can predict how long it would take for me to drop the ball of a roof using the $a = g$ approximation and basic kinematics. Electricity and magnetism experiments may in some cases require both a bit more equipment and a bit more care, but there are still many cool things you can do without really expensive equipment.

**Are there any test of the principles of quantum field theory that one can do using everyday objects or cheap equipment?** Also, it should be something that doesn't require special training to be safe to do.

Comment: The first thing I think of is Kaku building a cyclotron in his garage...but I'm not sure that counts.

Comment: Wait, what? How?!? Aren't those things huge?

Comment: http://bigthink.com/videos/an-atom-smasher-in-the-garage

Comment: If I went to Home Depot and bought 22 miles of copper wire, it would run me at least $30,000 and I would still have to connect the pieces somehow. Not to mention *400 pounds* of steel.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question. (Def not the cheap part.)

Comment: That's actually not bad though. I think that qualifies as cheap. Maybe I should modify the question so it doesn't sound like it has to be something just laying around the house. Buying 22 miles of copper wire is something any person could do if they had the money and space and if Home Depot was willing to supply it. You'd just have to be rich. But an athlete or musician could spend that kind of money easy. I think Bieber spent that much at a hotel last week.

Comment: I mean, its all about relative feasibility. If building an accelerator is what you have to do, then that puts some demanding constraints on how I can define "cheap" or else I have to accept no solution is possible.

Comment: Maybe the slit experiment? (QM is contained in QFT ?)

Answer (score -2):

No there's no Test Principles of Quantum Field theory using everyday objects, Since quantum field theory (QFT) is a theoretical framework for constructing quantum mechanical models of subatomic particles in particle physics and quasiparticles in condensed matter physics